# Entity Framework Core 2.0 Select Query with many-to-many problem

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Below is the model.

```
class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Categorization> Categorization { get; set; }
}

class Categorization
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Categorization> Categorization { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to list down all the Products and their Category as well.
API Code as below

```
foreach (var product in _context.Products.ToList()){
    var categories = product.Categorization.Select(c => c.Category);
    ...     
}
```

When we call the Api, I get this error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Select[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`product.Categorization` is null because it's not loaded.  If you're expecting lazy loading to handle the load you must make the `product.Categorization` property virtual (along with the properties you wish to lazy load in the `Categorization` class, `Category` in this case)

Edit: in your example you should eager load the data using `Include` and `ThenInclude` as you know you need the data:

```
_context.Products
   .Include( p => p.Categorization )
   .ThenInclude( c => c.Category )
   .ToList()
```

Comment: This is EFCore so making the properties virtual is not enough, it has to be configured : `The simplest way to use lazy-loading is by installing the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies package and enabling it with a call to UseLazyLoadingProxies` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading. Beside that it is only supported from EF Core 2.1

Comment: HI Moho, Thanks! I tried doing this but it gives me below error. services.AddDbContext<MetaDbContext>(
                b => b.UseLazyLoadingProxies(),
                opts => opts.UseNpgsql(connectionString)); Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ServiceLifetime' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @nemesv thanks, I stopped using lazy loading a long time ago for performance reasons.

Comment: @LavanyaPant - not sure, but in your current example you should eager load the data you know you'll use, updated the answer to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

For querying all products and their categories, you could try `Include` and `ThenInclude` like below:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllArticleAsync()
    {
        var articles = await _context.Articles
                               .Include(a => a.ArticleTags)
                               .ThenInclude(at => at.Tag)
                               .Select(a => new
                               {
                                   Id = a.Id,
                                   ArticleName = a.ArticleName,
                                   Tags = a.ArticleTags.Select(at => at.Tag).ToList()
                               })
                               .ToListAsync();
        return Ok(articles);
    }
```

For this way, you need to configure `opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling` in `Startup.cs` like below:

```
        services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

For a complete demo, refer [EFCorePro](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/tree/master/EFCorePro)

Answer (score 0):

Try add virtual to object like this:

```
class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Categorization> Categorization { get; set; }
}

class Categorization
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Categorization> Categorization { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rahy, I tried as you told but still get same error. Which version of EFCore you using ?

Comment: Adding `virtual` is not enough to get lazy loading in EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because `product.Categorization` is null.
Lazy loading is supported on Entity Framework Core 2.1 and above. Please check that Categorization for a specific product is not null and try to perform eager loading (although this might not be necessary according to the documentation)
For example:

```
foreach (var product in _context.Products.Include(p => p.Categorization).ToList()){
    if (product.Categorization != null) {
        var categories = product.Categorization.Include(c => c.Category).Select(c => c.Category);
        ...     
    }
}
```

Also please check that you have configured the many-to-many relationship correctly, as it requires that you define the composite primary key this way:

```
override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Categorization>().HasKey(c => new { c.ProductId, c.CategoryId});
}
```

Please check this tutorial as it might be useful: [Entity Framework Tutorial - Configure Many-to-Many Relationships](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx)

Comment: I think that your problem might be a different one. If you have configured everything correctly your code should work ok. The issue is that in the `foreach` it might be the case that a `Product` doesn't have `Categories` so you should check for null before getting the categories. I mean check `if (product.Categorization != null) { // assign the categories with the query ... } `

Comment: That i have make sure all product have category.

Comment: I modified my answer to reflect that. Please let us know if that worked. Regards

Comment: I upgrade my EFCore to 2.1.2 but now when I use "var product in _context.Product.Include(p => p.Categorization).ToList()" I get error   'DbSet<Product>' does not contain a definition for 'Include'

Comment: try adding `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` to the list of usings